# How do I pass React.createRef() to a child component?

Tags: reactjs

In my sidebar I have a list of radio buttons that should each select a component located in the main area of my app. I would like to set it so the component scrolls into view when I click the radio button that selects it, and as far as I can figure, I need to reference the component in order to scroll it into view, but I'm having trouble with this because I can't figure out how to properly pass a reference from child to parent component.

The parent component is a class component and in its constructor I set `createRef()` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.myRef = React.createRef();
}
```

I then created a function that should be passed to child component and return ref:

```
getElem(ref) {
  this.myRef = ref;
}
```

Now, inside the render of the parent component I pass the function to the child component like this:

```
<Designer 
  usedComponents={this.state.usedComponents}
  myRef={this.getElem}
/>
```

Inside the `Designer` component I map the main area components and pass the ref to them like this:

```
const components = props.usedComponents.map((component, index) => {
  return (
    <div onMouseUp={() => props.selectComponent(index)} key={index}>
      <DesignerComponent {...component} myRef={props.myRef} />
    </div>
  );
});
return components;
```

`DesignerComponent` component is determined through switch statement because each has a different set of props, but inside the switch statement I also pass `myRef={props.myRef}` to each individual component and then I set the ref inside each individual component like this:

```
<section ref={props.myRef}></section>
```

However, this breaks my app and gives me this error message:

> "TypeError: Cannot set property 'myRef' of undefined".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you will have to use [forward ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref)

Comment: I found this too but I can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: try setting your `const components = [Array].map((item) => React.forwardRef(props, ref) => <Component ref={ref} {...props}/>)`

Comment: Which one of the components is the parent component?

Comment: Everything referring to the first 3 blocks of code is inside the parent component.

Comment: try, forwarding your ref form parent to `Designer` as `<Designer ref={this.myref} />` and then inside the array as in my second comment, but I am not sure if you can pass ref to multiple components.

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The function getElem(ref) doesn't seem to do anything. I simply passed myRef={this.myRef} to the Designer component and now it works.